# Xymon Installation Confusion

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I'm trying to get Xymon running and I'm running into trouble.  Here's the specifics:

- VMWare ESXi 5.0
- Ubuntu 10.04 x64, clean install
- Very basic Xymon install--nothing crazy or complicated.

When I go to http://localhost/xymon (or http://hostname/xymon from another local computer) it just shows me the Apache index.  I'm not sure how to get it to actually display the site.  I'm suspecting the install got mangled somehow, but I don't know enough about this sort of thing to be able to tell where it went wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the file selinux, it should be in /etc/sysconfig/selinux. You may need to change disabled option in to permissive and then the reboot the system.
Also try to type in your browser: http://localhost/xymon/xymon.html.

Regards

Comment: Ubuntu does not have SELinux in use or enabled by default, it uses AppArmor.